# Comparing generic types using Comparable and Comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable

I've run into a headache I'm having difficulty debugging. I am trying to compare two generic values  so I can insertion sort them according to values into an array. This is my first time working with the Comparable and Comparator interfaces so any additional advice surrounding these issues would be great.

This is how my class is set up:

```
public class SVStore<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Pairs<K, V>, Iterable<K>, Comparable<V>, Comparator<V> {
```

The put() method:

```
@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {

    SVData<K, V> tab[] = table;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length - 1; i++) {
        if (value.compareTo(tab[i].dataValue) <= 0) {
            int index = i;
            for( int j = index; j < size - 1; j++){
                tab[j + 1] = tab[j];
            }
        }
        tab[i].setDataKey(key);
        tab[i].setDataValue(value);
        size++;
    }
    return value;
}
```

These are the compareTo() and compare methods I am trying to implement.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(V t) {
 return compare(t, this);
 }

@Override
public int compare(V t, V t1) {
    if (t.equals(t1)){
        return 0;
    } else if (t < t1){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The first issue I am running into is in the compareTo() method and it is centering around "this". The error says "required: V,V
  found: V,SVStore". I know the answer is not to cast "this" to V. How do I compare it to the V in that array index?

The second issue I am having is... } else if (t < t1){ in the compareTo() method. The error is "bad operand types for binary operator '<' first type:  V   second type: V". If it is recognizing both as V for both types why is it a bad operand?

I think all the code needed is there. I try to keep these as concise as possible, but if there's any additional code someone needs, I'm happy to provide it. Cheers!

Comment: What class is that `compareTo` method on? If it's on the `SVStore` itself, it doesn't make sense to compare the whole container to its components.

Comment: @chrylis - `compareTo`is in the SVStore. I have to humbly admit I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "compare the whole container to its components."

Comment: It looks like `SVStore` is some sort of container, like a map or database or collection or similar. It doesn't make sense to compare a `HashMap<String,Integer>` to a `String`; you compare the `String`s inside it to each other. (Or you compare two `HashMap`s to see if they have the same key-value pairs.)

Comment: @chrylis Data is actually stored in a separate inner class `SVData`. Keys and Values are stored in an array. `SVStore` contains the methods necessary to put(), remove(), etc. Not sure if that clears anything up for you.

Comment: For the first issue, as @chrylis points out is that you are trying to compare V with a collection (store) of Vs. Maybe you meant something like 'return [this.]contains(t);'.  
For the second issue, the whole function is in fact 'return t.compareTo(t1);', as V extends Comparable<V>

Comment: On second thought, you may drop your implements Comparable<V> (as @chrylis probably meant, you don't compare HashMap<String, Integer> with an Integer). Same with Comparator<V> - would be the equivalent of hashMap.compare(integer1, integer2).

Comment: @CatalinPol The second part makes sense and thank you, but for the first issue, 'return [this.]contains(t);'?? I'm a little confused by this. Are you saying return this in the compareTo() method? Did you intend to use that syntax? And also, would I then have to create a contains method? contains() would generally return a boolean value right? But compare() has to return an int. Am I missing something?

Comment: It never makes sense to implement `Comparable` and `Comparator` in the same class.

Comment: Yes, that was for the compareTo method, and it would require a contains method (the "this." part was optional... that what I meant by the brackets). Got confused with the types like you pointed out... like before, I'm not sure what to expect from a comparison between a value and a collection of values

Comment: I got it now thanks to a combined effort of everyone. Thank you!

Comment: for best results use `V extends Comparable<? super V>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the combined efforts of Chrylis, Catalin Pol, and Louis Wasserman, I learned I needed to correct my class to:

```
public class SortedValueStore<K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> implements PairStore187<K, V>, Iterable<K>, {
```

I no longer needed to write my own compareTo() method.

This did the trick. I'm relatively new to java so it took me a while to get what everyone was saying, but everyone was persistent with their efforts. Thanks to all for the help!